# Hot to get custom http-header in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, response, http-headers, custom-headers

I have an asp.net appliction on the one server. There I've added code on server-side in Page_Load:

```
Response.AddHeader("key", "password-key-from-hotel");
```

On the client side I have a form:

```
<form ... action="www.link-to-another-domaint" >
    <input type="hidden" id="asd" value="fgh" > 
    .... 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
</script>
```

Then on the other domain - there is also my other application - I'm trying to get the hedaer "key" by this code:

```
Request.Headers["key"].ToString();
```

But there is no such header. Is there is a desicion? Where is my mistake?

Comment: I would like to make something like Credentails like in the security access to the web-services, that's why I need this custom http-header.

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you need request field, not header. try:

```
Request["asd"]
```

Comment: No, I need to get the header "key" with the value "password-key-from-hotel".

Comment: @Sirius Lampochkin - how do you plan to request browser to send extra header? i don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding http header from the server-side and then trying to post form from the client-side.

So, you lose your header.

AFAIK, you cannot add http header from the client-side with form submit (as an exeption could be XHR and other plugins; but it seems, your post is cross-domain, so ajax won't work).

I don't understand the whole reason of doing it, but the easiest way to pass custom header from one page to another is to use `Server.Transfer` method.

Source page:

```
Response.AppendHeader("key", "password-key-from-hotel");
Server.Transfer("www.link-to-another-domain");
```

Destination page (even another domain):

```
string key = Request.Headers["key"];
```

This should work. But `Server.Transfer` method has its own [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx).

Comment: So... Is there a way to send a custom http-header from one domain to anoother?

Comment: @Sirius Lampochkin: yep, server-side form, server-side post and then redirect/transfer to the target page.

Comment: @Sirius Lampochkin: pass it using hidden input